# Convergence of Inverse Mellin Transform of $\Gamma(z)\sin((\pi z)/2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, mellin-transform

I have a question about an Inverse Mellin Transform. The Mellin transform of $\sin(x)$ is $$ \Gamma(z)\sin((\pi z)/2) $$ with a strip of definition of $-1 < \Re z < 1 $

My question is about taking the inverse Mellin transform of this function along the line $\Re z= a$ if $a > 1/2$:
$$ \int_{a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty} x^{-z} \Gamma(z)\sin((\pi z)/2)dz $$

How can I show that this integral converges if $\Re z > 1/2$?  Along a line parallel to the imaginary axis, the absolute value of the Gamma function has the asymptotic expression,
$$ |\Gamma(a+ib)|\sim \sqrt{2\pi} |b|^{a-(1/2)} e^{-|b|\pi/2} $$

So the modulus of the integrand as a whole is asymptotic to,

$$|\Gamma(a+ib)\sin((\pi (a+ib))/2)|\sim \sqrt{2\pi} |b|^{a-(1/2)}$$

along this line. Therefore, if $a>1/2$, the modulus of the integrand actually grows along this line, and in general, I believe this integral does not converge absolutely if $$ a\geq-1/2 $$

So I'd like to know how to show that the integral converges conditionally in this case and also how to justify using a Bromwich type contour so as to use residue theory to recover the power series for $\sin(x)$.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: With respect to the last paragraph, you need to evaluate the residues of $\sin \left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\, \Gamma (z)\, x^{-z}$ at the odd negative integers which results in the formula $$\sin (x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2 n-1)!}\, x^{2 n-1}.$$ Why do you need to evaluate the inverse Mellin transform at $\Re(z)>1$?

Comment: I assume you mean Re (z) > 1/2.  I'd just like to make sure I understand the theory -- in principle the inverse Mellin transform should converge if I integrate along any line in the strip of initial definition, and that strip extends to Re (z) <1, so I'm curious as to why the integral doesn't converge.  I suspect it's because $ x^{z-1} sin(x) $ is not in $L^2[(0,\infty]]$ for $ z>=0 $ so while the MT may exist, the IMT is not guaranteed to converge and it just doesn't for that portion of the SID.

Comment: Or rather $ sin(x) $ is not in $L^2$.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea is that if for $a<b$ we have $\int_0^c f(x)x^{a-1}dx< \infty, \int_c^{\infty} f(x)x^{b-1}dx< \infty$ for some positive $c$ then the Mellin inversion formula is valid for $a < \sigma=\Re s < b$ at least in a generalized form with the kernel $(1-|t|/T)$ so $\int_{-T}^T (1-|t|/T)F(\sigma+it)x^{-\sigma-it}dt \to 2\pi f(x), T \to \infty$ at the continuity points of $f$; in particular for $f(x)=\sin x$ the result above holds for $a=-1+\epsilon, b=1-\epsilon$ (with conditional convergence of course at infinity for $\sigma >0$), so inversion holds in the above sense at least

Comment: @Conrad -- Thank you.  To make sure I understand the general principle --  it is possible that there exists a function $f(x) \notin L^1_{[0,\infty]},L^2_{[0,\infty]}$ whose Mellin Transform, F(s) exists, and along the strip of definition grows like a polynomial as $ |\Im s| ->\infty$.  In this case the integral for the IMT exists in a generalized form, and we are guaranteed that in the strip, IMT(F(s)) = f(x).  But, I cannot, in general, use residue theory to evaluate such integrals (no matter the nice poles just sitting in the LHP) because F(s) no longer vanishes on the contours at infinity?

Comment: In general, if the Mellin transform has reasonable growth you can definitely evaluate back the function by moving the line to the left - the Mellin inversion theorem generally says that the Mellin inverse integral is summable to the original function in the strip where defined by the original integral, and IF it's convergent, the result is the function - kind of like with Fourier series

Comment: $\cos x$ is a good example since at infinity you need $\cos x /x^{1+\epsilon}$ for absolute convergence and at $0$ you need $\cos x /x^{1-\epsilon}$ for convergence, there won't be any abscissa $a$ where $(\cos x) x^{a-1}$ is absolutely convergent; however the above is conditionally convergent at infinity for $0<a<1$ and convergent at $0$ for $a>0$, so there is a strip of existence for the Mellin transform which is just $\Gamma (s) \cos (\pi s /2), 0 < \sigma <1$ with nice enough growth, so the inverse integral exists near $\sigma =0$ and can be moved to the left

Comment: >can be moved to the left<. 

Right, but if I understand correctly, we can use residue theory for cos x only because somewhere in the strip the MT decays to zero at infinity (for real part less than 1/2). Is this right?  If there were some pathological function that only had an MT with polynomial growth in the strip then I couldn't use residue theory, right?  Sorry to beat a dead horse here, just want to make sure I've got it. thx

Comment: >I couldn't use residue theory, right?<  Just to clarify I am hypothesizing this because immediately adjacent to the strip the MT wouldn't vanish by continuity and so the integrals at the "top" and "bottom" contours wouldn't vanish.

Comment: In theory probably you are right, but estimating growth rates from below of the Mellin transform (or of any oscillating integral) is tricky - here for $\sin, \cos$ you knew the result and that's how you estimated the asymptotic growth; similarly deciding whether an oscillating integral converges is very tricky as opposed to absolute convergence which is easy but rarer; see the $\cos$ example where the Mellin inverse integral is not absolutely convergent anywhere in the strip; overall I agree that one has to be careful for general statements and understand them in suitable meaning

Comment: Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to be of help - for subtler stuff about this would recommend Titchmarsh book on Fourier transform which is dense and difficult in many ways, but has lots of subtle results about convergence (as opposed to absolute convergence) and summability of oscillating integrals - from page $46$ on,  the results about Mellin mentioned above and more subtle ones are stated and proved

Comment: Fantastic.  Will definitely check it out.